# Is it possible to specify list parameters in an inventory file?

Tags: ansible

For example I have a file under `host_vars` that contains the following variable:

```
hosts:
  - xxx
  - yyy
```

Is it possible to specify a variable like that in an inventory file? I know you can specify a single value with `var=value` but not a list var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INI inventory files do not allow structured data like lists. As a work around, you can define a list in a group or host var file using exactly the notation in your question. Use the list in a play with a [`with_items` loop](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops).

For example:

```
$ cat playbook.yml
- hosts: [webservers]
  vars_files:
    - vars/webservers.yml
  tasks:
    - debug: host={{item}}
      with_items: hosts
$ cat inventory
[webservers]
web1
$ cat vars/webservers.yml
hosts:
  - xxx
  - yyy
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml

PLAY [webservers] *************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [debug host={{item}}] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=xxx) => {
    "item": "xxx",
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=yyy) => {
    "item": "yyy",
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to help. I don't want to define the variables inside the playbook I'd like to define them in the inventory file.

Comment: Updated the answer to state that structured data is not allowed in the inventory.

Comment: Thanks, this was my suspicion but I wasn't able to find an authoritative source.